# Call function at the end of Router.navigate

Tags: angular

I want to call a certain function after a user logs in. The user may log in from any page and on a successful log in, the user is redirected back to the previous page that they were browsing.

I'm using [Router.navigate](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigate) for redirecting to the page.

After looking for a while [NavigationEnd](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationEnd) seems like an option which would work, but it applies to *all* router events, not just a specific one.

My `login.component.ts` has something like this:

```
// ...
this.authenticationService.login(this.credentials)
  .pipe(first())
  .subscribe(
    data => {
      this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
      // Need to call a function `doSomething()` here.
    },
    error => {
      // Implement error handling
    });
// ...
```

I know that it's not a promise but I'm looking for something like:

```
this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl])
  .then(this.doSomething()); // or .pipe()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can navigate by using [`.navigateByUrl()`](https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigateByUrl) which returns a promise.

```
this.router.navigateByUrl(this.returnUrl).then(this.doSomething());
```

Comment: Perfect for my use case! Missed this in the API Docs.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest thing is to just listen for the `NavigationEnd` event like you mention, but stop listening after it happens.

```
this.authenticationService.login(this.credentials)
  .pipe(first())
  .subscribe(
    data => {
      this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
      this.router.events.pipe(
        first(evt => evt instanceof NavigationEnd)
      ).subscribe(() => {
        this.doSomething(); 
      });
    },
    error => {
      // Implement error handling
    });
```

I think this is the correct and safe thing to do because you know that:

1. There will be a `NavigationEnd` event coming
2. It will be the correct event to trigger your code
3. After that happens, you can stop listening

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
    if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        if(event.url === "your-route") {
            //do your thing
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look into using some sort of [lifecycle events](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)..  You could either do an OnDestroy in the component you are navigating from. Or a OnInit in the component you are navigating too.

Comment: This can take place from any component to any other component. I don't want to add the function in every component for this.